# Browse SQLite Database created in Virtual Device

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I have a simple SQLite database in a small project I'm working, I would like to browse the database and do custom queries and all of that, the same way I used to do it in PHPmyAdmin when working on a PHP project.

Is there any way to do this ? The database is created locally on the virtual device as far as I know, so I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For free version. Download SQLite browser and use.
Procedure is am my previous answer.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-view-and-locate-sqlite-database-in-android-studio/

https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/

Comment: I will try this plugin and let you know if it works, thank you

Comment: Thank You. it should work for DB's created within the Application /data folder or inside a separate folder created in SD card.

Comment: Oh this stuff requires me to buy a license, this ain't it chief.

Comment: I have updated my answer. check it out please

Comment: Thank you for the help my friend !